# What is wrong with my fragment implementation?

Tags: android, fragment, looper, ioio

Intro: I have an IOIO-OTG Board that is attached to an android device via a USB connection. My IOIO-OTG board is supposed to launch a looper upon connection, however this never seems to happen.

The only reason I believe it doesn't seem to happen is because when I implement fragments into the class it won't launch the looper, however if I just use a regular IOIOActivity instead of a IOIOFragmentActivity (which I created); it all works fine. However then I cannot use fragments.

If anyone has any ideas on this matter about what could be blocking my inner looper class from being created and called that'd be appreciate.

My Code:

```
package com.example.ioiofinal;

import ioio.lib.api.AnalogInput;
import ioio.lib.api.DigitalInput;
import ioio.lib.api.DigitalOutput;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIO;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIOFactory;
import ioio.lib.api.PwmOutput;
import ioio.lib.api.TwiMaster;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.IncompatibilityException;
import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOFragmentActivity;

import java.util.Locale;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends IOIOFragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    IOIO ioio;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DigitalFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DigitalFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DigitalFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "Digital";
        String TAG;
        // Declare all the UI Variables
        TableLayout centralDigitalTable;
        View digitalfragmentview;

        Switch digitalIO0Power;
        Switch digitalIO1Power;
        Switch digitalIO2Power;
        Switch digitalIO3Power;
        Switch digitalIO4Power;
        Switch digitalIO5Power;
        Switch digitalIO6Power;
        Switch digitalIO7Power;
        Switch digitalIO8Power;
        Switch digitalIO9Power;

        Switch digitalInput0Power;
        Switch digitalInput1Power;
        Switch digitalInput2Power;
        Switch digitalInput3Power;

        Switch[] digitalIOPowerSwitchArray = new Switch[10];
        Switch[] digitalInputPowerSwitchArray = new Switch[4];

        Context superContext;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle SavedInstantState) {
            superContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            digitalfragmentview = viewInflation.inflate(
                    R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

            digitalIO0Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio0power);
            digitalIO1Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio1power);
            digitalIO2Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio2power);
            digitalIO3Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio3power);
            digitalIO4Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio4power);
            digitalIO5Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio5power);
            digitalIO6Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio6power);
            digitalIO7Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio7power);
            digitalIO8Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio8power);
            digitalIO9Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalio9power);

            digitalInput0Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalinput0power);
            digitalInput1Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalinput1power);
            digitalInput2Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalinput2power);
            digitalInput3Power = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalinput3power);

            centralDigitalTable = (TableLayout) digitalfragmentview
                    .findViewById(R.id.digitalTable);

            digitalInputPowerSwitchArray[0] = digitalInput0Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[0] = digitalIO0Power;
            digitalInputPowerSwitchArray[1] = digitalInput1Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[1] = digitalIO1Power;
            digitalInputPowerSwitchArray[2] = digitalInput2Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[2] = digitalIO2Power;
            digitalInputPowerSwitchArray[3] = digitalInput3Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[3] = digitalIO3Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[4] = digitalIO4Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[5] = digitalIO5Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[6] = digitalIO6Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[7] = digitalIO7Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[8] = digitalIO8Power;
            digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[9] = digitalIO9Power;

            return digitalfragmentview;
        }

        // BEGIN SWITCH RELATED METHODS 
        public Switch getIOPowerSwitch(int index) {
            return digitalIOPowerSwitchArray[index];
        }

        public Switch getInputPowerSwitch(int index) {
            return digitalInputPowerSwitchArray[index];
        }
        // END SWITCH RELATED METHODS

        public TableLayout getCentralDigitalTable() {
            return centralDigitalTable;
        }

        public void setCentralDigitalTable(TableLayout centralDigitalTable) {
            this.centralDigitalTable = centralDigitalTable;
        }

        public View getDigitalFragmentView() {
            return digitalfragmentview;
        }

        public void setDigitalFragmentView(View digitalfragmentview) {
            this.digitalfragmentview = digitalfragmentview;
        }

    }

    class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

        DigitalFragment digfrag = new DigitalFragment();
        /** The on-board LED. */
        private DigitalOutput led_;

        // TWI Corresponds to the pins with CLx and DAx
        private TwiMaster t1;
        private TwiMaster d1;
        private TwiMaster t2;
        private TwiMaster d2;

        // Corresponds to UI Switches DO 0-11
        private DigitalOutput DO1;
        private DigitalOutput DO2;
        private DigitalOutput DO3;
        private DigitalOutput DO4;
        private DigitalOutput DO5;
        private DigitalOutput DO6;
        private DigitalOutput DO7;
        private DigitalOutput DO8;
        private DigitalOutput DO9;
        private DigitalOutput DO10;
        private DigitalOutput DO11;
        private DigitalOutput DO12;

        // Corresponds to UI Switches DI 0-8
        private DigitalInput DI1;
        private DigitalInput DI2;
        private DigitalInput DI3;
        private DigitalInput DI4;
        private DigitalInput DI5;
        private DigitalInput DI6;
        private DigitalInput DI7;
        private DigitalInput DI8;
        private DigitalInput DI9;

        // PWM corresponds to pins 27-30
        private PwmOutput PWM1;
        private PwmOutput PWM2;
        private PwmOutput PWM3;
        private PwmOutput PWM4;

        // Analog Inputs correspond to pins 31-46

        private AnalogInput AI1;// 31
        private AnalogInput AI2;// 32
        private AnalogInput AI3;// 33
        private AnalogInput AI4;// 34
        private AnalogInput AI5;// 35
        private AnalogInput AI6;
        private AnalogInput AI7;
        private AnalogInput AI8;
        private AnalogInput AI9;
        private AnalogInput AI10;
        private AnalogInput AI11;
        private AnalogInput AI12;
        private AnalogInput AI13;
        private AnalogInput AI14;
        private AnalogInput AI15;
        private AnalogInput AI16;

        private DigitalOutput[] DOA = { DO1, DO2, DO3, DO4, DO5, DO6, DO7, DO8,
                DO9, DO10, DO11, DO12 };

        private DigitalInput[] DIA = { DI1, DI2, DI3, DI4, DI5, DI6, DI7, DI8,
                DI9 };

        private TwiMaster[] TWIA = { t1, d1, t2, d2 };

        private PwmOutput[] PWMA = { PWM1, PWM2, PWM3, PWM4 };

        private AnalogInput[] AIA = { AI1, AI2, AI3, AI4, AI5, AI6, AI7, AI8,
                AI9, AI10, AI11, AI12, AI13, AI14, AI15, AI16 };

        /**
         * Called every time a connection with IOIO has been established.
         * Typically used to open pins.
         * 
         * @throws ConnectionLostException
         *             When IOIO connection is lost.
         * 
         * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#setup()
         */
        @Override
        protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "LOOP WAS SET UP",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            led_ = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(0,true);

//          led_ = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(0, true);
//
//          for (int i = 0; i < DOA.length; i++) {
//              DOA[i] = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(i + 6);
//          }
//          for (int i = 0; i < DIA.length; i++) {
//              DIA[i] = ioio_.openDigitalInput(i + 18);
//          }
//          for (int i = 0; i < PWMA.length; i++) {
//              PWMA[i] = ioio_.openPwmOutput(i + 27, 10000);
//          }
//
//          for (int i = 0; i < AIA.length; i++) {
//              AIA[i] = ioio_.openAnalogInput(i + 31);
//          }
//          TWIA[0] = ioio_.openTwiMaster(1, TwiMaster.Rate.RATE_1MHz, false);
//          TWIA[1] = ioio_.openTwiMaster(2, TwiMaster.Rate.RATE_1MHz, false);
//          TWIA[2] = ioio_.openTwiMaster(4, TwiMaster.Rate.RATE_1MHz, false);
//          TWIA[3] = ioio_.openTwiMaster(5, TwiMaster.Rate.RATE_1MHz, false);
        }

        /**
         * Called repetitively while the IOIO is connected.
         * 
         * @throws ConnectionLostException
         *             When IOIO connection is lost.
         * @throws InterruptedException
         * 
         * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#loop()
         */
        @Override
        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {
            led_.write(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < DOA.length; i++) {
                DOA[i].write(true);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A method to create our IOIO thread.
     * 
     * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity#createIOIOThread()
     */
    @Override
    protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
        return new Looper();
    }

}
```

**Again, my problem is that if I simply change MainActivity extends IOIOFragmentActivity to MainActivity extends IOIOActivity all works well and the looper is created and called; however then I am unable to use fragments!**

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use the IOIO from an application with fragments, but not using the IOIOFragmentActivity that you are using. So in case you are still stuck here is what I did.

Basically I send data to the IOIOService from the fragment using a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) that is read by the service.

The fragment that will call the IOIOService class:

```
public class LightLevel extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

Intent IOIOIntent;

// Messenger for communicating with the service. */
Messenger mService = null;

// Flag indicating whether we have called bind on the service. */
boolean mBound;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lightlevel_fragment, container,
            false);

    IOIOIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), IOIOConnection.class);
    getActivity().startService(IOIOIntent);

    // Bind to the service
    getActivity().bindService(
            new Intent(getActivity(), IOIOConnection.class), mIOIOConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    return view;
}

public void sendData(float v) {
    if (!mBound)
        return;

    // Create and send a message to the service, using a supported
    // 'what' value
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, IOIOConnection.LIGHT_LEVEL,
            (int) rate, 0);
    try {
        mService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mIOIOConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = new Messenger(service);
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;

    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().startService(IOIOIntent);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().stopService(IOIOIntent);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        getActivity().unbindService(mIOIOConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    getActivity().stopService(IOIOIntent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        getActivity().unbindService(mIOIOConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    getActivity().stopService(IOIOIntent);
}
```

And then the Fragment that deals directly with the IOIO:

```
public class IOIOConnection extends IOIOService {

    static final int LIGHT_LEVEL = 1; //this to compare with the incoming message
    float _sensorValue = 0;    //variable for the incoming data

    /**
      * Handler of incoming messages from clients.
      */
    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case LIGHT_LEVEL:
                //Capture the incoming data
                _sensorValue = msg.arg1;
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
 */
final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

/**
 * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger for
 * sending messages to the service.
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

I hope it helps.